# What Firestore Security Rule matches an empty map? [Bug?]

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Here are some Firestore security rules that I've tried to use to match an empty map in a "create" rule:

```
request.resource.data.myMap == {}

(request.resource.data.myMap is map &&
 request.resource.data.myMap.size() == 0)

(request.resource.data.myMap is map &&
 request.resource.data.myMap.keys().size() == 0)
```

I've double-checked that the thing I'm putting is indeed an empty map by changing the security rule to:

```
request.resource.data.myMap is map
```

...and examining the database from the Firebase Console. It contains an "object" with no fields -- which is, as I understand it, an empty map.

I'm guessing this is a bug. If not, how can I match an empty map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This no longer seems to be an issue. request.resource.data.myMap == {} now seems to work.